# How to specify a range of values (from start to end) within an array list and from user input

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> listOfNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    int inputNumber;

    while (true) {
        inputNumber = Integer.valueOf(inputReader.nextLine());
        if (inputNumber <= -1) {
            break;
        } else {
            listOfNumbers.add(inputNumber);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("From where? " + inputNumber);
    System.out.println("To where? " + inputNumber);
    System.out.println(listOfNumbers);
}
```

I am trying to input random numbers `[10, 20, 30, 40 and 50]` to an array list, after I input -1 the while loop will stop running and the array list will stop collecting numbers.

After that, I want the user to input a first and an end value (index) assuming that the user knows how many numbers there are in an array list, to retrieve a range of values and after the loop is broken. Let's say the user inputs 10 and 30, the output should be `[10, 20 and 30]`

How can I do such a thing inside the main method and without calling other methods?

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem you faced. You already solved the 'hardest' part, so I assume that you know how to get two additional numbers from the user. The last thing is to iterate over the list to output only those numbers which are in range. So, what's the problem?

Comment: @Mihe, unfortunately I cannot get new numbers from the input user, because the last number i input is -1 to break the loop. When I try to print out 'from where' and 'to where' the number -1 is already inputted there. I want to input 2 new numbers from that array list and output them as a range of values

Comment: Sure, because you don't read anything after the loop. Just read another value from the inputReader and assign it to some variable (e. g. just like thanbv1510 did in his answer).

Comment: Use a for loop with an if statement that checks if the number is within the range.  if it is, print it.